# Can we bring back the Gray bar?

Tags: feature-request, design, top-bar

Just wondering, how can I bring back the gray color to my status bar on top of my screen? This black one makes it hard to read the gray fonts (Also it is too dull) ._.

My bad: Please replace orange with gray.

[image: the top bar: where is the orange?]

Comment: Ummm... It was never orange? It used to be a light grey.

Comment: @animuson I think it was orange at stackoverflow.

Comment: It definitely wasn't.

Comment: @animuson is right.  It was light grey,http://i.stack.imgur.com/1FnVr.png

Comment: Well, there *was* [an orange bar](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/05/revamped-notifications/) at one point, @animuson... Kinda shocked that anyone would want it back though.

Comment: @animuson Thanks I mistakenly took it with the orange message bar. How do I bring the gray one back